# kubernetes/minikube / Warning Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using kubernetes/minikube and I've tried to install my application docker image by using a POD configuration yaml file as follow:

So far so good but problem starts just when I try to build my pod by executing:
`kubectl create -f employee-service-pod.yaml -n dev-samples`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: employee-service-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: employee-service-cont
      image: doviche/employee-service:latest
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]
  restartPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: employee-service-secret
```

status: {}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOgkx.png)

When I checkout my POD does show the following error:
Back-off restarting failed container

Soon after I ran:
`kubectl describe pod employee-service-pod -n dev-samples`
which shows what is on the image attached to this post:

Honestly I have not been able to identify what's causing the Warning and that's why I've decided to share it with you to see if some good eye sees the arcane.

I appreciate any help as I am stuck on this since so long

I am using minikube v1.11.0 on Linuxmint 19.1.

Many thanks in advance guys.

Comment: If you can put the `describe` output in a code block rather than an image, it will be much easier to see what might be going on for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application completed its work successfully (echo SUCCESS) since you have mentioned **restartPolicy of the container as Always**, it is trying restart again and again and going to crashLoopbackoff state.

Please change the container **restartPolicy: OnFailure**, this should mark the pod status completed once the process/command ends in the container.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks a lot Kiruba! It works but my pod status as follow:  Initialized True
Ready False
ContainersReady False
PodScheduled True

Comment: With all these statuses in mind, does it mean that I can invoke my application? I ask you this 'cause of the Ready status set to false.

Comment: Good to hear, please accept the answer if it solved your problem.